# how copy / scp files via gsutil to google cloud VM?

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am playing with linux VM in GCP.
Any idea how copy files from local machine to GCP VM via scp gsutil SDK ?

this command not working:

```
gcloud beta compute scp file user@test01:
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.scp) Could not fetch resource:
 - The resource 'projects/pyton-app/zones/europe-west3-a/instances/test01' was not found
```

But I can login via ssh with below gsutil command

```
Cloud beta compute ssh --zone "europe-west3-c" "test01" --project "pyton-app"
```

Here are other options:

```
gcloud beta compute scp 
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.scp) argument [[USER@]INSTANCE:]SRC [[[USER@]INSTANCE:]SRC ...] [[USER@]INSTANCE:]DEST: Must be specified.
Usage: gcloud beta compute scp [[USER@]INSTANCE:]SRC [[[USER@]INSTANCE:]SRC ...] [[USER@]INSTANCE:]DEST [optional flags]
  optional flags may be  --compress | --dry-run | --force-key-file-overwrite |
                         --help | --internal-ip | --plain | --port | --recurse |
                         --scp-flag | --ssh-key-expiration |
                         --ssh-key-expire-after | --ssh-key-file |
                         --strict-host-key-checking | --tunnel-through-iap |
                         --zone
```

...yes, instance is in this project as I can login via ssh, but unable to copy via scp.. trying also your advice command, but not working also

```
gcloud beta compute scp r.script user@test01:/tmp  --project "pyton-app"
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.scp) Could not fetch resource:
 - The resource 'projects/pyton-app/zones/europe-west3-a/instances/test01' was not found
```

Tried also 2nd option, not working also

```
gcloud compute scp r.script user@test01:/tmp  --project "pyton-app"
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.scp) Could not fetch resource:
 - The resource 'projects/pyton-app/zones/europe-west3-a/instances/test01' was not found
```

Comment: Is this instance in the project `pyton-app`? If not, add the command-line option `--project=pyton-app`. Another item, when specifying the destination include a path `user@test01:/myfolder`. These commands have product (GA) versions, unless you have a specific reason, do not use BETA commands.

Comment: Under your question is an "edit" link. Use that to improve your question with more details instead of adding a comment (for more details or clarity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't in the correct zone.

Look at the error message

```
- The resource 'projects/pyton-app/zones/europe-west3-a/instances/test01' was not found
```

-> europe-west3-a

Look at your ssh command

```
gcloud beta compute ssh --zone "europe-west3-c" "test01" --project "pyton-app"
```

-> europe-west3-c

For solving this, 2 solutions:

- Add the zone in your scp command

```
gcloud beta compute scp --zone "europe-west3-c" file user@test01:
```

- Set the zone by default in your gcloud config

```
gcloud config set compute/zone europe-west3-c
```

Comment: thx, it works now, reg.  your post for default zone, do u know how to setup default zone for BigQuery dataset location ? because it ignore this option and still create dataset in US by deafult

Comment: No, I don't see [this param in the possible values](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/properties). And there is [nothing to set by default in the bq cli](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference)